# Disable Submit until checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, submit

Have a simple problem but for a noob, I can't see what the issue is. Basically, I'm trying to disable a submit button until a checkbox has been selected (several checkboxes as data being taken from MySQL). However, have tried multiple variations and have had no luck. Have copied in below - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There is not much use in disabling the submit button when you have an onclick handler on the checkbox that calls submit anyway...

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzmmuoLm/), but you have problem with `#Seat`. You know you can't have multiple `id`s in the DOM, another issue is you're binding (I believe) more than checkbox because I noticed `name="Seat[]"`

Comment: You should tag your question with php, as you included php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action='something' method='POST'>
   <input type='checkbox' name='chk' value='1' id='check'>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' disabled='disabled'>
</form>



 <script>
    $('#check').click(function(){
          if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
             $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
          }else{
               $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
     });
    </script>
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple fiddle that I made:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxs39zvp/1/)

```
var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var button = $('#check');

if(checkbox.is(':checked')){  
  button.removeProp('disabled');
}else{  
  button.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}

checkbox.on('change', function(){
 if(checkbox.is(':checked')){  
  button.removeProp('disabled');
}else{  
  button.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
} 
});
```

Edited to include several checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your check boxes have a unique `id`, so add the number from your query, just like you did for the value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Seat[]"
       id="Seat<?php echo $row['SeatNo'];?>"
       value="<?php echo $row['SeatNo'];?>"
       onclick="checkThis();updateTextArea();updatePrice();submit();"/>
```

Assuming you want at least one check box to be checked to have the submit button enabled, use the `is(':checked')` call on the group of checkboxes to check if at least one is checked. If not any is checked, disable your button, otherwise enable it:

```
$(function() {
    function setSubmitAvailability() {
        // disable button when no checks, otherwise enable:
        $('#check').prop('disabled', 
            !$("[name=Seat\\[\\]]").is(':checked')
        );
    }
    // call on check box click:
    $("input[name=Seat\\[\\]]").click(setSubmitAvailability);
    // call also on page load:
    setSubmitAvailability();
});
```

Note that you want to select the checkbox elements by name, in order to detect a check among any of them. So then you don't use the `#`, but `[name=...]` selector. Furthermore, brackets are reserved characters in selectors, so you need to escape them. Since backslash is also an escape character in Javscript strings, you need to double those.

In the above code, near the end, I also call the function immediately while the page loads, to set the submit button's availability correctly at page load as well. This is necessary as some browsers keep check boxes checked when you reload the page. So you cannot assume one or the other setting for the button without looking at the checks on page load.

As you have not provided the code for what happens in the `onclick` handlers, there might still be other things you need to change to make this work. But without those handlers the above code works.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6j4bg10/2/).

Answer (score 0):

just write disabled in input type Submit

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Booking" id="check" disabled>
```

then copy the code

```
<script>
$(function() {
                $('#Seat').click(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#check').removeAttr('disabled');

                } else {
                     $('#check').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```